# How do you index a text column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, datatypes

If I create a table with a `text` column

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( bar text );
```

I can't index the `bar` column.

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE INDEX foo_bar_idx ON foo ( bar );
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'bar' used in key specification without a key length
```

If I `HELP CREATE INDEX`, I get,

```
Syntax:
CREATE [ONLINE|OFFLINE] [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_option] ...

index_col_name:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]

index_type:
    USING {BTREE | HASH}

index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
  | COMMENT 'string';
```

`KEY_LENGTH` not mentioned only `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE`, but if I use it as an option, I get

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE INDEX foo_bar_idx ON foo ( bar ) KEY_LENGTH = 5;
ERROR 1911 (HY000): Unknown option 'KEY_LENGTH'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In MySQL Key Length is added as a type-modifier and placed in parenthesis `colname()`, you can provide it to `CREATE INDEX` like this,

```
CREATE INDEX foo_bar_idx ON foo ( bar(500) );
```

It's part of `index_col_name`, (except it's not optional on text so ignore the `[]`)

```
index_col_name:
  col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]
```

Alternatively you may want an Full Text Search (FTS) index instead providing `MATCH` functionality

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX foo_bar_ftsidx ON foo ( bar );
```

For more information see the [MySQL docs on Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: `bar(500)` is also called a "prefix".  I find that `INDEX` is almost never useful, whether applied to `TEXT` or some other datatype.

Comment: `INDEX` is almost never useful -- what do you mean?

Comment: For most 'range' queries, the index is totally ignored.  You can't say `UNIQUE` without understanding that the constraint applies only to the prefix.  'Point' queries might work, but that is only a subset of possible queries.  I forget what other cases there might be.  (Did you want to play tag on this question, too?  Hehe.)

Comment: what is FOO and what is BAR ? tablename or colname or indexname?